# Keeping a ruby script running in terminal so I can call different methods

Tags: ruby, shell

I want to call a ruby script and keep it running while I call methods on it.

I have:

```
 until (a = gets.chomp) =~ /(?:ex|qu)it/i
  send(a)
 end
```

This works very well, but I feel like it can't be the best practise?

Can someone reassure me / provide a better solution?

Comment: How do you want to use it exactly?

Comment: why don't you use irb (ruby console) ?

Comment: I can't seem to accept stdin using IRB without closing the process

Answer (score 1):

If you want a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), you could use IRB or PRY.
Otherwise you could [write it yourself](https://jpsilvashy.com/posts/build-a-simple-ruby-repl.html) :

```
def handle_input(input)
  raise StopIteration if input =~ /^(ex|qu)it$/i
  result = eval(input)
  puts("=> #{result}")
end

def repl(prompt)
  print prompt
  handle_input(gets.chomp!)
end

loop do
  repl('>> ')
end
```

Example :

```
>> 2+3
=> 5
>> "test".size
=> 4
>> 3.times{|i| puts i}
0
1
2
=> 3
>> exit
```

Using `eval` usually isn't a good idea. But with your `send`, you cannot specify a receiver or any parameter.